# SequenceGenerator error: not a valid function or procedure name

Tags: jboss, ejb, hql, ejb-3.0

I have an EJB 3.0 client and server with JBoss AS 7.1.1. I'm trying to persist a list of entities to the database I'm connected to but I keep getting this error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06576: not a valid function or procedure name
```

I have a sequence generator called `SEQ_ID` in my Oracle database. I followed this tutorial in setting it up: http://www.developerscrappad.com/408/java/java-ee/ejb3-jpa-3-ways-of-generating-primary-key-through-generatedvalue/

Here is my entity bean that uses the annotations in the above tutorial on the primary key: http://pastebin.com/QJ6W5VLG

Here is my function that persists the list of entities:

```
public void persistSchemas(List schemasList){
    String strDelete = " DELETE FROM Schemas s ";
    Query query = em.createQuery(strDelete);
    query.executeUpdate();

    for(Schemas schema : (List<Schemas>)schemasList){
        em.persist(schema);
    }
}
```

Here is the full stack trace of the error on the server:
http://pastebin.com/rmURYdRD

The error only shows up when I try to persist the entities and they have the two annotations @SequenceGenerator and @GeneratedValue. So it's definitely something going on with the sequence. What is wrong here?

Comment: What's the SQL query executed by Hibernate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that the HQL dialect was wrong. I needed to change it to:

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle8iDialect"/>
```

In my persistence.xml in the META-INF folder of my server.